# Write trailing newline as byte into binary output file in Scheme

Tags: file, binary, filesystems, scheme

I have problem with my code, I'm not able to save newline using binary port, I want to write unit test for my Scheme implementation but I'm not able to figure out why I got this results also in Gambit and Kawa (Gauche and Guile fail to run the code, because of missing procedures).

```lisp
(let ((fname "./tests/__x7__.scm")
      (str "hello, world!\n"))
  (if (file-exists? fname)
      (delete-file fname))
  (let ((port (open-binary-output-file fname)))
    (call-with-port port
                    (lambda (p)
                      (write-bytevector (string->utf8 str) p)))
    (define output (with-input-from-file fname
                     (lambda ()
                       (let ((result (list)))
                         (do ((char (read-char) (read-char)))
                           ((eof-object? (peek-char))
                            (apply string result))
                           (set! result (append result (list char))))))))
    (write output)
    (newline)))
```

I'm writing newline into file but in output file I don't have newline at the end and when I read the file I get `"hello world"` instead of `"hello world\n"`.

What's weird is in my Scheme implementation that I want to test I also get `"hello world"` without the newline.

If the string is `"hello, world!\nfoo bar"` the newline is saved properly, why the trailing newline is not saved?

What I missing here? Why newline is not saved into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newline is saved into the file: checking the file with `od` or something will show you that.

However your logic *reading* the file is incorrect: you never do anything with the last character you read.  If you instead wrote (say)

```
(let loop ((c (read-char)) (a '()))
  (if (eof-object? c)
      (list->string (reverse a))
      (loop (read-char) (cons c a))))
```

You will get all the characters from the file.